# Download and overwrite existing file in macOS

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have a file on my computer that the developer often updates and stores online. I am running an automatic job (cronjob) every hour using this file. I am looking for a way to start the job by downloading and overwriting this file from internet and proceed with the standard job as it is now. This way, I will always be using the latest version of the file.

I am using MacOS.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `curl` to download the file from the script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Barmar! I was able to fix using curl. Below is the code I used to download and overwrite:

curl http://Location_of_file/file > file